# Generate MDX from external MD content with Gatsby

Tags: wordpress, markdown, gatsby, mdx

I currently have a Gatsby site that builds with MDX files as well as pulling content from WordPress to build pages. I have a MD plugin on my WordPress site so I can write and preview markdown for my blog posts.

I would like to be able to add custom components from the content that is written in WordPress, like I currently have in my MDX files.

Is there a way to convert the MD content from WordPress into MDX content? I am still doing a build with createNode for the data pulled from WordPress, although it has a different structure (content field holds the MD and other custom fields are included in the schema).